# Как дать возможность администратору менять пароль пользователя в системе Identity?

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

В своем ASP.NET MVC 5 проекте я использую систему авторизации и аутентификации от Microsoft - ASP.NET Identity. При регистрации пользователя в БД (в моем случае это PostgreSQL) записывается не пароль, а его хэш. На моем сайтике есть администратор, и необходимо чтобы он имел полный доступ к редактированию данных пользователей, в т.ч. и пароль, но так как пароль записан в виде хэша я не могу этого сделать. Что можно сделать в данной ситуации?

Comment: ничего. Пароль должен знать только юзер. Админ не может узнать уже существующий пароль, но вы можете дать админу возможность установить новый пароль для юзера.

Comment: @tym32167 как дать админу возможность установить новый пароль для юзера?

Comment: Насколько я помню, у `UserManager<Т>` есть специальные методы для смены пароля существующего юзера

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете явно поменять пароль, используя `UserManager`

```
 // находим юзера
 var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);

 // генерирум новый пароль
 var password = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 6);

 // создаем токен для смены пароля
 var resetToken = await userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);

 // меняем, не забывая потом вывести или сообщить пароль юзеру :)
 await userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, resetToken, password);
```

Comment: разве это не для Core проекта? у меня MVC.